# How to pass down constructor parameters transparently or how to use bind in class expressions?

Tags: javascript

### Problem:

Given these classes:

```js
class A {
    public constructor(private n: number) {
        //
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static readonly X = new class B$X extends B {
    }("abc");

    public static readonly Y = new class B$X extends B {
    }("def");

    public constructor(private s: string) {
        super(1);
    }
}
```

with B having some static fields that are created from class expressions, how can I specify individual values for A's constructor, without modifying B's constructor?

That value `1` in B's ctor should not be hardcoded by somehow set from the class expressions, without adding that number to the constructor parameter list.

### Background:

This is an attempt to convert a Java enum to a Typescript class. The Java compiler internally generates some code, which I have to model explicitly. Imaging something like:

```java
enum B {
    X("abc"),
    Y("def");

    private String s;

    B(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

An enum is implicitly derived from `java.lang.Enum` which has a constructor to take the enum constant's name and its ordinal and I have to model that manually. I can generate the code for the class expressions, but I don't know how to pass through the values for constant name and ordinal.

I was thinking of binding the constructor of the class expression, but cannot imagine how that syntax has to look like.

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't do this with inheritance at all. I'd use an "enum factory" function that takes some description of the desired properties and returns a frozen object that provides the constants and whatever else.

Comment: Because I need to maintain the Java semantics here, I have to use inheritance. `java.lang.Enum` has other functionality I have to support (later).

Comment: Well best of luck, seriously, but I swore off trying to think in Java while writing JavaScript a very long time ago :)